# Laravel php artisan produces error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have integrated and working in a Laravel 5.4 project. I was actually configure this correctly and `php artisan` command was working perfectly before.But in between the development time(I have implemented the schedule task using laravel and not sure after that issue appear) it produces m error on php artisan commands. Can anybody help me on this.

The following is the error log for the command for any artisan command

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error:
>   Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php
>   on line 60 in
>   /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:103
>
> ```
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/projrct/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(60):
> ```
>
> Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection),
>   NULL)
>       #1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(290):
>   Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
>       #2 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(746):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closur in
>   /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php
>   on line 103

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of your error messages! Copy and paste them into your question with proper formatting.

Comment: @milo526 thanks for quick reply and i have done the changes.

Comment: i its not an artisan error, i think you have error syntax somewhere in you routes or controllers files

Comment: Whether you created any CommandController(Used for schedule task) file for schedule task?

Comment: @Mohammad Alfaz Yes i am. I have created a scheduled task and created command class under app/Console/Commands/Sample.php

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I my case url() helper function in my filesystem.php is causing the issue. I removed it and every thing works fine.

Comment: I had the same in a config file.

Answer (score 63):

Please make sure that you are not using any url() or asset() or other helpers functions inside your configuration files

Comment: Yes exactly that was the reason i found it and forgot to update here. Anyways thank you for your response.

Comment: When I hunt finding solution you save me brother. This tricks working also laravel 7.X Thank you!!!

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative solution to commenting out the `url()` and `asset()` calls could be to check the environment at run time:

```php
return [
    'URL' => app()->runningInConsole() ? '' : url(''),
    ...
];
```

Comment: This is the correct way to handle this error, saves you from commenting the `url` function call every time you wish to use artisan

Comment: the best way yeah !

Comment: This should be the selected answer. I needed to set a url path for an image that would be sent over emai. I could not hardcode it since it would not work on local/staging environment. This solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If Really Need The Function To Be Inside Your Config, You Could use [PHP_SAPI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)
To Check Weather The App Is Running HTTP or CLI,

```sh
'redirect'  =>  PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? false : url('synchronise')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, when you are running any artisan command you should avoid using `helper` functions in any of your `config` files. Just comment those and try to run artisan command after running that uncomment your `config` files.

```
//in config/'any_file.php'
return [
   'name'   => 'Larvel',
   'url'    => url('/')
];

//just change and uncomment url() helper
return [
   'name'   => 'Larvel',
    //'url' => url('/')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got stuck at same issue while I was using asset in config file (adminlte.php) of Admin LTE.

Please comment your asset, url while using artisan command in config files like this

```
[
    'type' => 'js',
    'asset' => false,
     // 'location' => asset('js/waitme/waitMe.min.js'),
],
```